# Ajax call is failing but isn't throwing an error when debugging

Tags: c#, ajax

My **AJAX call** is used to send data from **JS** to **C#** so i can use it **server side**. My call seems to be resulting in an **error** throwing the alert('Failed'). I am running my solution in the visual studio debugger but there **isn't an error**. I have tried so much to fix this issue but not sure why it isn't working.

**Why would this be failing if there arent any errors?**

AJAX call -

```
function get_email(){
    var test_email = $("#email_entry").val();
    console.log(test_email);
    $("#email_entry").val('');

if ((email_validate(test_email)) == true) {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "WebForm1.aspx/GetData",
        contentType: "application/text; charset=utf-8",
        data: test_email,
        dataType: "string",
        success: function (result) {
            alert('Works');
        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert('Doesnt work');
        }
    });

}else if ((email_validate(test_email)) == false) {
    alert("Email is not valid!");
}
}
```

C# where the data is being stored

```
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public class EmailStore
        {
            public string Email { get; set; }
        }

        [WebMethod]
        public static void GetData(string test_email)
        {
            String a = test_email;
            Console.WriteLine(a);
        }
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the browser devtools console?

Comment: No there arent any in there either. I get an asp.net event when I submit the email where it says call to an HTTP handler is initialised but nothing after that.

Comment: var text_email = $("#email_entry").val();  console.log(test_email); you misspelled the variable name text_email to test_email

Comment: Secondly, try this -  data: "test_email="+test_email

Comment: Sorry, I changed the variables names for this post they are all correct, I will try that now though.

Comment: Thirdly, why this statement has different variables? public static void GetData(string person_email)
        {
            String a = test_email;
            Console.WriteLine(a);
        }. I think it should be like this GetData(string test_email). [WebMethod] must have variable name same as query parameter variable, I suppose.

Comment: Like I said I changed a few of the variables for the sake of this post, missed one now edited it. I tried changing the data value but still no luck. Thank you for your suggestions though.

Comment: Change `dataType: "json"` and change `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` and finally `data: JSON.stringify({test_email: test_email}),`.

Comment: Wow! Thats it. Thank you very much @HamedMoghadasi. I'll put that as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your `$.ajax()` as below:

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "WebForm1.aspx/GetData",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify({test_email: test_email}),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            alert('Works');
        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert('Doesnt work');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I do notice you are not returning a status from your c# method to respond if it was a success or not.
In ASPNetCORE c# you return results to an ajax call like so:

```
public IActionResult GetData(string person_email)
    {
     try
        {
        String a = test_email;
        Console.WriteLine(a);
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(a) ? 
        (IActionResult)BadRequest("email null or empty") : Ok();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return BadRequest(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for this comment, haven't developed the C# yet just wanted to get the AJAX call working, good suggestion though!